# Cannot mount iPod touch to Ubuntu due to Lockdown errors

Tags: 13.10, downloads, ipod, lock

I sit before you with the common question of how to sync an iPod 5G or any iDevice to Ubuntu 13.10. I have asked Apple tech support many a time aswell as their online chat and it has yielded no info besides going to Canonical which said that they cannot help me either because I need to be a paying customer.

So...

How do I do it?

I have tried iFuse and libimobiledevice-utils and it has yielded no results

For those who wish to know the errors, they are, "Unhandled Lockdown error (-256)", "Unhandled Lockdown error (-3)", "Unhandled Lockdown error (-5)", "Unhandled Lockdown error (-6)" etc.

Help please.

Thanks

Mo.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the permissions of ~/.config/libimobiledevice/*.pem from 644 to 600. My ipod connected fine after that.

```
chmod 600 ~/.config/libimobiledevice/*.pem
```

Obviously that was after installing libimobiledevice.

Comment: Did you do this in Ubuntu 13.10? Can you provide a step by step procedure to walk the user through the process? This would improve your answer significantly.

Comment: This answer does not solves issues for 14.04. under the directory .config, libimobiledevice directory does not exists.