# Unhandled Lockdown error (-256)

Tags: 14.04, unity, iphone

Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS up to data packages while writing these.

Looks like paired when type i`idevicepair list` but get this error message when click on the nautilius to iPhone.

[image]

---

From [Cannot mount iPod touch to Ubuntu due to Lockdown errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414925/cannot-mount-ipod-touch-to-ubuntu-due-to-lockdown-errors) it is suggested to install `libimobiledevice-utils` but ...

```
da@xps15z:~$ sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... 
Done libimobiledevice-utils is already the newest version. 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

this did not create `~/.config/libimobiledevice/`

Comment: I do not mean to be rude but, the link you gave does not provide an answer. So I opened the question. Maybe I might have write to there?

Comment: Yes I tried, and get a message as "no such directory". [:

Comment: I have libimobile installed.

Comment: da@xps15z:~$ sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libimobiledevice-utils is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded. Also reinstalled nothing changed.

Comment: I would have done it like this ;) comments removed and added to the question.

Comment: I know this is an older question, but I too am having the exact same issue running on Debian Jessie. I verified libimobiledevice-dev (1.1.6), libimobiledevice-utils (1.1.6), and usbmuxd (1.0.8) are installed. Also, the directory `~/.config/libimobiledevice/` wasn't created. I would love to hear any progress which might have been made to solve this issue.

Comment: Install the lastest stable version from web.